# jquery change button text from save to edit 2 ways

Tags: javascript

i newbie in programming and wanna ask how to change button 2 way.

```
<button type="button" id="button">Save</button>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button').click(function(){
     $('#button').text("Edit");
      });
       });
```

initial when i click i turn to "Edit" then how to click back to "Save" when clicking.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a small toggle function:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text(function(_, value) {
        return value == 'Save' ? 'Edit' : 'Save';
    });
});
```

Comment: @GreenCat If another answer has been useful, you can choose to upvote it (using the up-facing arrows next to the score). Acceptance can be done for only one answer.

Comment: can help me another problem? another stupid question-sorry ..from select <option value="01">January</option> <search> so when go to another pages i view by using <?php echo $this->input->('month');?>..how can i view January instead of 01

Comment: @GreenCat You will have to ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple ternary operator will do it:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Save' ? 'Edit' : 'Save');
});
```

Or you can pass a function to `.text()`:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GxLXQ/)**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(this).text(function(_, val){
        return val == 'Save' ? 'Edit' : 'Save';
    });
});
```

Comment: The callback passed into `text()` will receive the current text as the second argument, so that you don't need to call that method again to retrieve it.

Comment: another stupid question-sorry ..from select <option value="01">January</option> <search> so when go to another pages i view by using <?php echo $this->input->('month');?>..how can i view January instead of 01

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var editing = false;
    $('#button').click(function(){
        editing = !editing;
        if (editing) {
            $('#button').text("Edit");
        } else {
            $('#button').text("Save");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button').click(function(){
if( $('#button').text()=='Save')
       {
      $('#button').text("Edit");

        }

  else

       {
       $('#button').text("Save");

           }
      });
       });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2m5q7/